# TeamCity Server not working with Rspec/Turnip/Capybara Integration Test

Tags: rspec, continuous-integration, teamcity, capybara, gherkin

I have been writing integration tests for a web app in [rspec](http://rspec.info/), [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), and [turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip).

When I run the tests on my local machine using rake :name_of_task on the command line, it works, with browser popping up and everything. My rake task is here:

```
desc "Run Integration Tests"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:integration_test) do |t|
  t.pattern = 'spec/*'
  t.rspec_opts =  ["--format documentation", "--format documentation", "--out spec/rspec_logs/rspec_log.txt"]
end
```

In TeamCity I have made a build configuration to run the tests, with the following options:

Runner Type: Rake

Launching Parameters : use 'bundle exec'

Attached Reporters: RSpec

When I run the build, I got a sucess...only nothing ran!

```
[Execute idme:integration_test] /opt/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/92c98e465299a9e1/spec/extension_helper.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant FIREFOX_PROTOCOL
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] 
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] Starting.. (0 examples)
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] 
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] 0 examples, 0 failures, 0 passed
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] 
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] Finished in 0.000370012 seconds
[11:50:34][Execute idme:integration_test] 
[11:50:34][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 0
```

I'm not really sure what to make of this.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I've a similar issue - I've added rspec tests to a build which already uses Test::unit, successfully, but the rspec tests are ignored. I've seen that you need to provide user options, or it'll be ignored, but I've not found where the user options are listed